# Custom forms feature in QGIS: QMessageBox.warning closes QDialog as well

Tags: qgis, python, pyqt

I am attempting to work with custom forms in QGIS. I have included a validate function in my code that will pop a QMessageBox() if the validation fails. My problem is that when I close the QMessageBox the QDialog also closes without giving me the chance to modify its contents. Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

form = None
name_field = None

def form_open(my_dialog, layer_id, feature_id):
    global form
    global name_field

    global name_field
    form = my_dialog
    name_field = form.findChild(QLineEdit, "field")
    button_box = form.findChild(QDialogButtonBox, "buttonBox")
    button_box.accepted.connect(validate)
    button_box.rejected.connect(form.reject)

def validate():
    #This function validates that all of the required fields have been completed correctly.
    results = list()
    results.append(validate_field(name_field, "str"))

    if False in results:
        msg_box = QMessageBox()
        msg_box.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msg_box.setWindowTitle("Field")
        msg_box.setText("Please complete the Field")
        msg_box.exec_()
    else:
        form.accept()
```

I won't to be able to close the QMessageBox and go back to my initial QDialog window. Anyone kind enough to take a look?

Comment: Have you looked into ignoring the close event of the msg_box. http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcloseevent.html

Comment: Thanks, I am struggling with your suggestion now :). Can you be a little more specific  ?

Comment: You need to override closeEvent() by subclassing the message box. Then the overridden closeEvent could be something like def closeEvent(self,evnt): evnt.ignore(). I haven't put this as an answer as it's more of a suggestion and will require you to work it into the code

Comment: Yes, I figured that much but the implementation is more difficult than I can handle ..

Comment: Wouldn't this work if you use `msg_box.open()` instead of `msg_box.exec_()` ?

Comment: no it doesn't, msg_box.exec_() is needed to visualise the MessageBox. My problem is that the defined form is a QgsAttributeForm and I don't know how to re-write/override the closeEvent() function in this case. I also don't know how to capture the events in my code.

Comment: I think it is not the `QMessageBox` which closes your dialog. It is the click on the Okay button of the `QDialogButtonBox` which closes your window directly after closing the message box. I tried to disconnect the `button_box.accepted` signal via `button_box.accepted.disconnect()` but it always fires the signal no matter what I try... Others seem to have same problem before - see this link https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10739 and this one: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74640/buttons-ok-cancel-disappear-in-apri-modulo-from-attribute-table-in-qgis-2-0

Comment: Found out that also `form.disconnectButtonBox()` from `QgsAttributeFrom` (see http://qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeForm.html), which is meant to disconnect signals, is not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Please see also my comments and especially see the links to similar issues to understand this WORKAROUND.

As the`QDialogButtonBox` signals somehow cannot be disconnected, or the `QAttributeForm` somehow "listens" to the button box - I simply delete it and exchange it with my own "Okay" and "Cancel" `QPushButtons`. Note: Displacing the original button box with a new one will re-connect signals, so that clicking on the buttons will close dialog again.

I connect the "Okay" button with the `validate()` function and save changes to layer and close dialog if input is valid. 
I connect 'Cancel' button with `resetValues()` and close dialog.

My code looks like this then:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import (
    QLineEdit, QDialogButtonBox, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox)

form = None
field = None


def form_open(my_dialog, layer_id, feature_id):
    global form
    global field

    form = my_dialog
    field = form.findChild(QLineEdit, "field")
    button_box = form.findChild(QDialogButtonBox, "buttonBox")

    # Delete original button box:
    button_box.deleteLater()
    # You could hide it also:
    # form.hideButtonBox()

    # Add own buttons and connect them correctly:
    # Don't add ButtonBox - this will be connected to close slot again!
    bt_okay = QPushButton('Okay')
    bt_cancel = QPushButton('Cancel')
    bt_cancel.clicked.connect(form.resetValues)
    bt_cancel.clicked.connect(form.parent().close)
    bt_okay.clicked.connect(validate)

    # Add buttons to horizontal layout:
    h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    h_layout.addWidget(bt_okay)
    h_layout.addWidget(bt_cancel)

    # Find QVBoxLayout from QAttributeFrom and add horizontal layout:
    v_layout = form.children()[1]
    v_layout.addLayout(h_layout)


def validate():
    results = list()
    # Append your tests here - Example test:
    results.append(str(field.text()) == 'test')

    if False in results:
        msg_box = QMessageBox()
        msg_box.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msg_box.setWindowTitle("Field")
        msg_box.setText("Please write 'test' into the Field")
        msg_box.exec_()
    else:
        form.save()
        form.parent().close()
```

`QMessageBox` works fine and the rest seems to work also.
Please give feedback if I missed something!

Answer (score 1):

Since QGIS 2.16, there is a new functionality called "form constraints"

Go to the form configuration in the vector layer properties, configure a widget and define a constraint. With no python involved at all.

[image: Constraints in action]

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog216/index.html#feature-constraints-on-widgets